# VB.NET VSTO for PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: vb.net, interop, vsto, powerpoint, page-setup

I am creating a PowerPoint Add-in. I have created Ribbon buttons which when clicked opens Windows Forms. However, how can I communicate from the forms to the active presentation? For example, how to get the active presentation's height and width to two text-boxes in the form when a button (in the form) is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

An example is:

```
Text1.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 72
```